# Angular ng-include in wrong position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I try to include a template with angular `ng-include`. The page to include to:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th translate>
              First
            </th>
            <th translate>
              Second
            </th>
            <th translate>
              Third
            </th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <ng-include src="getTemplate('default')"></ng-include>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

The template:

```
<tr class="table-row-clickable">
  <td>text1</td>
  <td>text2</td>
  <td>text3</td>
</tr>
```

Get template method:

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(templateName) {
    return APP_CONFIG.TPL_PATH + '/path/' + templateName + '.html';
};
```

The template loads fine, I can see it on the page, but in the wrong place. Here is the screen from my browser's console, the `ng-include` inserts before the table, not inside it:
[image]

Could you please help me to understand, why is that? Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1, add browser's render:**
[image]

Comment: I would put ng-include on the tbody tag directly, i.e. `<tbody ng-include></tbody>`

Comment: I was just about to write what @Dwardu said. ng-include doesn't use "replace" so i think the browser might decide it's in the wrong place and move it outside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers follow HTML standard, so there can't be any other tag like `ng-include` inside the `tbody` tag. There should be only `tr`

```
<tbody>
    <ng-include src="getTemplate('default')"></ng-include>
</tbody>
```

So, change it to:

```
<tbody ng-include="getTemplate('default')"></tbody>
```

This will simply put the content of the template inside the `tbody`.

**Note**: Your code might work on some browser as other browsers might render it as is but might show different in the inspector. For example: if you miss a closing tag of a `div` (for example), and when you inspect the element, you will see the closing tag since some browsers like Chrome will auto close for you (although, your page rank for search engines like Google might fall).

Try to use some extension like [Web Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) and use a feature like **See generated output**

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you. Good answers are easy ones )